# How does adb find the USB port #?

Tags: android, adb

When I run *"adb devices -l"*, it is able to display the USB port info as "**usb:xxxxxxx**". Does anyone know how adb pulls this info? I'm trying to figure out how I may be able to do this with idb so I can get the same USB info for the attached iPhones. Thanks!

qelabadmin@DevFarm ~ % adb -P 5037 devices -l

List of devices attached

17061FDEE000BN         device **usb:338825984X** product:raven model:Pixel_6_Pro device:raven transport_id:25

96081FFBA00052         device **usb:338768384X** product:coral model:Pixel_4_XL device:coral
transport_id:18

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-8.1.0_r9/adb/transport.cpp#921

Comment: That must be something Linux specific, on Windows there is no `usb:...` device property.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you can use

```
ioreg -p IOUSB
```

and it lists something like

```
| +-o your device (2022)@14400000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x0...>
```

and if you convert the hex to decimal

```
0x14400000 => 339738624
```

it's the number displayed by `adb`:

```
XXXXXXXX             device usb:339738624X product: blah, blah
```

Comment: Hi Diego. You have a much greater understanding of ioreg than I do. Can I ask one more question and see if you may know the answer? If I have 2 iPhones attached and I run the above, my output would look something like this `| | | | +-o iPhone@14311120 <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1120be9f1, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 23> | | | +-o iPhone@14311400 <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1120d66e8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 23>` How can I tell which is which iPhone? Do you know what that id field is referencing? I can't find that info.

Comment: Try adding `-w0 -l` to the command line to get more properties displayed. It could help.

Answer (score 0):

you would use the command "lsusb" on Linux and MacOS